# when data change in data model state in redux, i can not catch change event with useeffect in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

when datamodel poinst changed data in the state, i want to capture this change with useffect, but now i can capture it, how can i capture.

const [urlList, seturlList] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    seturlList(props.url.urlList);
  }, [props.url.urlList])
```

;

```
const initState = {
  urlList: [
    {
      id: 1,
      points: 5,
      linkName: "Stackoverflow",
      linkURL: "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      points: 5,
      linkName: "amazon",
      linkURL: "https://www.amazon.com/",
    },
  ],
};
```

Comment: for instances; when points increase or decrase, useffect doenst catch this changing.

Comment: The dependency array in your useEffect means it will only update if props.url.urlList changes. That is probably the problem

Comment: @axnyff is there any way?

Comment: I don"t really understand your code, you should provide a reproduction of your problem

Comment: have you connected your component with the `redux` store